# Is it necessary to put the <td> inside a <tr>

Tags: html, css

```
<TR class="bcgrndClr">
  <span class="Title">
    My title
  </span>
</TR>
```

I wrote this part, but the **background color** is not coming in chrome and other browsers, where as working fine in "IE".

so is it necessary to put a `<td>` before `<span>`
or should i go for `<th>` instead of `<tr>`

or how else should i give the title (with some conditions) to this particular table

Comment: Yes, if you want valid HTML its necessary. What's the big deal? It's an extra 9 characters...

Comment: `<th>` is not a substitute for `<tr>`. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp

Comment: Is your question to use `<th>` vs `<td>`?

Comment: If you don't. Either it won't work, or it will work :-) [based on the DOCTYPE]. If it *does* work, it's because the browser did the work of inserting the TABLE, TBODY, TR elements into the DOM for you. Go look with FireBug, they're there!

Comment: It's technically not working fine in IE, it's working despite the fact that it shouldn't. A browser is working correctly if it follows the standard, and there's no standard as to how row background color should be handled when there's a lack of cells.

Comment: thats not the prob.. thing is whether i should go for <td> or shud make <tr> as <th>

Comment: You should use `<tr>` and then either `<td>` or `<th>` depending upon whether you want HTML to express it as a header or just data. See the link I provided in my other comment.

Comment: yes thts my que. j08691,
@David-skyMesh, i already added TABLE TBODY TR etc

Comment: @mbratch thats actually not the column header but the Title for whole table.. thats why i m asking , can i use <TH> instead of <TR > directly

Comment: i m very much new to this thing @DanAndrews thats y confirming whether i m doing it right...

Comment: If you were concerned about doing it right, this wouldn't be a question as you'd see the specification for the tag.

Answer (score 4):

TH and TD are interchangable, but not TH and TR.  Thats how i been using it at least.

you can do something like:

```
<tr><td colspan="2"><span>Hello World</span></td></tr>
```

colspan is used to make a TD element stretch across multiple row elements.

Comment: This is a very elegant answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need `<td>`. Browsers will still try to render the table if you write invalid HTML, but the rendering will be inconsistent between browsers.

`<th>` can take the place of `<td>` if the cell is a header cell. It does *not* take the place of `<tr>` which is always required.

You can always check the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/tr.html) if you are in doubt about which elements are required and which are optional:

> The tr element represents a row of cells in a table. Permitted
>   contents Zero or more of: one td element, or one th element

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#edef-TR) or [HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element), you will see

**HTML 4:**

> ```
> <!ELEMENT TR       - O (TH|TD)+        -- table row -->
> <!ATTLIST TR                           -- table row --
>   %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
>   %cellhalign;                         -- horizontal alignment in cells --
>   %cellvalign;                         -- vertical alignment in cells --
>   >
> ```

**HTML5:**

> **4.9.8 The tr element**
>
> **Content model:** Zero or more
>   td, th, and script-supporting elements

Notice the `TH` and `TD`? Those are the only two child elements allowed.

What happens when you add an invald element to the `TR` is up to the browser. Some will try to figure out what you are doing, others will remove it from the flow and add it after. Write valid code so the browser does not have to guess.

Since you have a class of title, it seems like you should not be using a row. If you want a title row on the table, you want to use the [`<caption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption) element.

**From MDN:**

> The HTML `<caption>` Element (or HTML Table Caption Element) represents
>   the title of a table. Though it is always the first descendant of a
>   `<table>`, its styling, using CSS, may place it elsewhere, relative to
>   the table.

**Basic usage:**

```
<table summary="Description Text">
    <caption>My Table Of Numbers</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>C 1</th>
            <th>C 2</th>
            <th>C 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1-1</td>
            <td>1-2</td>
            <td>1-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2-1</td>
            <td>2-2</td>
            <td>2-3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>C 1</th>
            <th>C 2</th>
            <th>C 3</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vM688/

Answer (score 0):

According to spec, a `tr` can contain **only** `th` and `td` elements. As other have said, don't be lazy and write the few extra characters to make your HTML valid

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- text b/w <th></th> will bold and center aligned by default -->
            <th> You title here </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <!-- Content of you table here -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry, but it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

A td tag stands for table data whereas a tr tag is a table row.
So you make a row in HTML and then add a td to it the number of tds you add decides the number of columns in that row.
A th tag stands for table heading which can be used in a row.

The background color will show if you add the span tag inside the td. Your code will look somewhat like this:

```
<table><tr class="bg-color"><td><span class="title">My title</span></td></tr></table>
```

And the css should go like:

```
.bg-color{background:#ff0000;}
```